# when I debug a C program , I meet this mistake:The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am a new to C programming. I met the mistake: (The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1) when I debug, like this:

[image]

and my launch.json is :

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - 生成和调试活动文件",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my tasks.json is :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Click on the button "show errors" and correct them.  You are failing to compile the source file.  Feel free to post the errors if you do not understand them.

Comment: already the 3rd time today: Who  is teaching that `"type": "cppbuild"` is valid?

Answer (score 1):

> "program": "${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",

1. You need to give the directory name, containing your file,  in `{fileDirname}`
2. You need to give the name of the executable in `{fileBasenameNoExtension}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are from China. Please check:

1. If the folder of your program contains non-English words. (for Chinese, don't create the folder in Desktop "桌面")
2. If you have whitespace or other characters that may affect compiling. In my case, my folder contains a "&" and, when I look up the command VSCode generated for me, the command doesn't contain everything after '&' and cannot find the right executable.

It's a good practice to make your folder name clean. Hope this helps!